# parsing blocks of text within a text file (blocks separated by empty line)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, text-parsing, string-parsing

I'm a brand new Python user who wants to parse a text file that looks like this:

```
$ begin
$ vertex -1285.6 -226.2 -538.7 0
$ track 11 1000 0.7277 0.6765 0.1133 0
$ end

$ begin
$ vertex -1265.3 573.1 1547.7 0
$ track 11 1000 -0.7679 0.1650 0.6189 0
$ end
```

For every block ($ begin ... $ end) I want to get vertex coordinates x y z:

```
$ begin
$ vertex x y z 0
$ track 11 1000 -0.7679 0.1650 0.6189 0
$ end
```

Can somebody suggest a way to do this?
I am very grateful for any help or advice!

Comment: Iterate through the first column and check for vertex.. If vertex is found then grab your co-ordinates and store it in a list.

Comment: Hi Teja, Thanks for the advice. Can you provide a code sample if its not too much work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's presume you have a text file called my file.txt with your data in it.
And let's give labels to each of the items in the row:

```
marker = $
label = vertex OR track OR begin, etc
x = your x value
y = your y value
z = your z value
eol = the last value on the vertex line
```

As we read each line, we can check to see if the line includes the term 'vertex'.

If it does, we then split that line using the split function (be default, split will split on whitespace, but let's explicitly call out what we want to split on (ie. ' '). Split produces a list of elements.

We can the use tuple unpacking to break each item out of the list and assign them individual labels so our code is more readable. We can then print the values. In your case, you probably want to save or process those values... just replace the print statement with your processing code.

```
file = open('myfile.txt')
for line in file:
    if 'vertex' in line:
        fields = line.split(' ')
        marker, tag, x, y, z, eol = fields
        print(x, y, z)
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!!! I awarded you the check mark because you gave such a clear explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex here.

```
patern = re.compile("\n\n")
print patern.split(content)
```

Explanation: This will look for patern of two consecutive new line characters in your string and split into array with that pattern

For example:

```
   with open('data.txt', 'r') as myfile:
       str=myfile.read()
       #str="hello world \n line 1 \n line 2 \n\n line 3 line 4 \n line 5"
       print str
       patern = re.compile("\n\n")
       print patern.split(str)
```

Result:
    ['hello world \n line 1 \n line 2 ', ' line 3 line 4 \n line 5']

Comment: Hi alpeshpandya, Thanks! Can you explain what this does? I'm a little confused. Maybe can you provide an example?

Comment: Added explanation and example

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

with open('data.txt','r') as f:
     text = f.readlines()
for line in text:
    if 'vertex' in line:
        fields = line.split(' ')
        print(fields[2],fields[3],fields[4])
```

Comment: why are you importing csv?

Answer (score 0):

Short and sweet with a touch or `re`

```
import re
verticies = re.findall('\$ vertex (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) 0', open('t.data').read())
print verticies
```

Gives:

```
[('-1285.6', '-226.2', '-538.7'), ('-1265.3', '573.1', '1547.7')]
```